# search form for custom fields

Tags: posts, customization, search, advanced-custom-fields, location-search

I want to create a custom search for pin code search with custom fields value.

When exact match with pin code will show the post data

Can you please help me?

Any help in this matter would be appreciated.

Comment: Already I have created a post type "location" But need Help for the custom search form and  search result page

Comment: Include what you've done so far - at this point any attempt to help would be futile because there's no information available to help put together a solution.